# C - program not working right, what am I missing?

Tags: c

I am learning C and I have to make a program where you input a string and call the function which tells you 2 letters which repeat the most times in the string. But the function returns the wrong letters. The thing is, I've used a snippet from program I made before, so I don't know why isn't it working now.

Here is the function that is troubling me, I think the problem is in the second for loop, because if I printf the number of repeating of each letter of the alphabet, it is exactly as it should be, number of repeats of each letter is correct when compared to the string. But the 2nd for loop still doesnt return correct letters.

```
void najcescaSlova( char *niz, int *znak) {
    int i, slova[26]={0}, duljina=0, znak1, znak2;

    while (niz[duljina] != '\0')
        ++duljina;

    for (i=0; i < duljina; ++i) {
        if (niz[i] >= 'A' && niz[i] <= 'Z')
            ++slova[niz[i] - 65];

        if (niz[i] >= 'a' && niz[i] <= 'z')
            ++slova[niz[i] - 97];
    }

    znak1 = znak2 = -1;

    for (i=0; i < 26; ++i) {
        if (slova[i] != 0) {
            if (slova[i] == znak1) {
                 znak2 = i;
            }

            if (slova[i] > znak1) {
                znak2 = znak1;
                znak1 = i;
            }

            if (slova[i] < znak1 && slova[i] > znak2) {
                znak2 = i;
            }
        }
    }

    znak[0] = znak1;
    znak[1] = znak2;

    return;
}
```

I'm sorry, the program is in my native language, but I can close and reopen the question if you want.

slova[26] is the array in which number of repeats of each letter is saved.

niz is the input string.

znak1 and znak2 are the two of the biggest letters, while znak1 is treated as the biggest.

The thing here is, slova[0] is 7 and slova[2] is 5, so when i=0, znak1 is set to 0, as 0 represents A, but when i=2, znak1 is set to 2, which represents C, even though the if(slova[i] > znak1) condition is not fulfilled, slova[i], which is 5, is smaller than znak1, which was earlier set to 7.

Sorry if this is too long and thank you for your time.

Comment: Please [edit] your question so that it contains meaningful information. *Program not working right* is already clear (if it were working right you wouldn't need to post here), and *what am I missing* is simply meaningless noise. Your title should be descriptive of the actual problem you're having, in a way that will be meaningful to future readers who see it in a search result.

Comment: the hard coded values `65` and `97` are 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers make the code more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  Suggest using: 'A' and 'a', respectively to replace the 65 and the 97

Comment: the hard coded value `26` is a 'magic' number.  'magic' numbers make the code more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  Suggest using a #define to give the number a meaningful name and using that meaningful name throughout the code/

Answer (score 1):

When you write `slova[i] == znak1` and `znak1 = i` you are confusing the concepts of the 0-25 letter index held by `i` and the count of the number occurrences, held in `slova[i]`.

In your second `for` loop you need two variables to hold the first and second highest counts found, and also another two to hold the index of the letters that correspond to those counts (could use `znak[0]` and `znak[1]` for these, but I'm not sure if the variable naming becomes strange at this point). An example is here (assumes `znak` array is initialised correctly):

```
    for (i=0; i < 26; ++i) {
        if (slova[i] != 0) {
            if (slova[i] == znak1) {
                 znak[1]= i;
                 znak1 = slova[i];
            }

            if (slova[i] > znak1) {
                znak[1] = znak[0];
                znak[0]= i;
                znak2 = znak1;
                znak1 = slova[i];
            }

            if (slova[i] < znak1 && slova[i] > znak2) {
                znak[1]= i;
                znak2 = slova[i]
             }
        }
    }
```

Here I have used `znak[0]` and `znak[1]` for the first and second most common letters, and `znak1` and `znak2` for the frequencies of those letters.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that it is not clear what `znak1` and `znak2` mean? Are they the indices or the values of the biggest letters?

If they are indices, then comparisons such as `slova[i] == znak1` is wrong. It should be `slova[i] == slova[znak1]` instead.

But if they are values, then assignments such as `znak1 = i`, is wrong. It should be `znak1 = slova[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

You have used `znak1` and `znak2` as both - array indices (`integers`) and the value of the largest letters (`char`).

If you mean to use them as array indices then change `slova[i] == znak1` to `slova[i] == slova[znak1]`.

If they are supposed to be the largest letter values, then the `znak1 = i` and similar assignments are incorrect. Instead, you should use `znak1 = slova[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

in the following answer, the code will pick the first occurrence of a high value, when there are multiple entries with the same high value.

1. Always try to localize data
2. Always try to write the simplest code that still does the work

all the convoluted code beginning with:

```
znak1 = znak2 = -1;
```

and the the local declarations of znak1 and znak2

can be replaced with the following simple code:

```
    for (int i=0, znak_x = -1; i < 26; ++i)
    {
        if (slova[i] > znak_x)
        {
            znak_x = i;
        }
    }

    // eliminate this high count from the slova[] array
    slova[znak_x] = 0;

    // save the high count index into the caller's array
    znak[0] = znak_x; 

    for (int i=0, znak_x = -1; i < 26; ++i)
    {
        if (slova[i] > znak_x)
        {
            znak_x = i;
        }
    }

    // save the second high count index into the caller's array
    znak[1] = znak_x;
} // end function:  najcescaSlova
```